# How to see dynos waiting time in heroku new logs format?

Tags: logging, heroku

Heroku used to have this pieces of information in their log:

```
[...] wait=10ms service=228ms [...]
```

where

- **wait** how long is the request waiting in the router for free dyno
- **service** how your app takes for responding

Now their is logs looks like:

```
[...] connect=2ms service=131ms [...]
```

does **connect** is the same as **wait** ?
or is it another metric? In that case what does it mean?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#info-logs) it looks to be "amount of time spent establishing a connection to the backend web process"